# Where could I ask an ethics question about signers on a multi-sig wallet?

Tags: discussion, topic, scope

Let's say seven people who are well known in the Ethereum community were invited to and are now participating as signers on a 4-of-7 multi-sig wallet that holds a large amount of funds for a Web3 project. You are one of those signers, and another of the signers (with whom you are acquainted but not really friends) has joked with you about the idea of getting four of the signers to agree to rug the project. Of course, it's just a joke...or is it? You are concerned that this person may be putting out feelers to see if there is actually enough interest among three of the other signers to actually attempt the heist. Not wanting to unnecessarily cause drama in the project's community, but also concerned over the chance that this signer is no longer acting in good faith, what would be the best approach for how to handle this situation?

Is there a Stack Exchange community that this question would be suitable for?

(just a hypothetical situation)

Comment: Probably reddit.com/r/ethereum

Comment: This is just basically a trust problem. No technology can (fully) solve a trust problem.